# Finding an item using 'if' condition while iteration vs using get(key), when you already need to iterate anyway

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm already iterating over several hashmaps each of sizes 20-40 items so would it make more sense to find an item just by adding an `if` condition while iterating or using a single `get(key)` operation ? Which approach would give more performance.

I know for accurate results I should rely on profiling results but since I'm not too familiar with profiling, wanted an expert opinion.

## Edit:

Here is my code:

```
    for (HColumn col : lobColumns) {// lobcolumns is a list but I also have hashmap already built containing same elements as this list
        switch (ByteBufferToInt(col.getName())) {

            case .......:
                break;

            case .......:
                break;
            case .......:
                break;
            case .......:
                break;
            case .......:
                break;                  
        }            
        if (ByteBufferToInt(col.getName()).intValue()==currentUserId()){// here is what I'm using as replacement for hashmap `get()`
            .....
        } 
    }
```

`lobcolumns` is a list but I also have hashmap already built containing same elements as this list. This list/map contains a few constant & a few variable objects, for constants I use switch case for efficient lookups & for finding a single special variable item I need to need to decide whether to use hashmap `get()` or using `if` while already iterating.

Comment: If your already iterating over the `map`, your not getting the performance benefits of the `map`. In that case I suppose it's "better" to use if condition than to do another look up on the map if you must.

Comment: Actually I get both a hashmap as well as list passed by an external libray & I already need to iterate over the list

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, because your question doesn't say anything about a list.

Comment: Why do you need to iterate?  Please explain the reason behind that.

Comment: even if you're already iterating, `if` will compare every time, `get` will do the lookup in constant time. If the maps stay in your 20-40 entries size, i don't think it matters, but for larger maps stay with `get`

Comment: @jlordo well it will matter as it will be a linear scale (microseconds are microseconds at the end of the day)

Comment: If performance matters to you, don't listen to anybody on this thread, and microbenchmark it for yourself using Caliper or something. Performance at this scale is crazy unintuitive. If saving nanoseconds isn't critical in this part of your app, then go with what makes your code read more clearly. I suspect that'd be a `get()`call but it's hard to say without seeing the code in context.

Comment: @Woot4Moo exactly what I'm saying ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I mean let's look at it.  The `get` operation is `O(1)` or constant time with a **perfect hash** function in the worst case.  Whereas iteration is `O(n)` in the worst case.  If you have the `key` ahead of time just invoke `get` there is no need to iterate over everything.

**Update**

The following line:

```
for (HColumn col : lobColumns)
```

Your comment was that you have all of these values stored in a `HashMap` already.   If the map is defined as so:

```
Map<Integer, HColumn> columns = new HashMap<Integer,HColumn>();
```

The `if` statement moves outside of the for loop and becomes the following:

```
HColumn column = columns.get(currentUserId());     
if(null != column)  
{  
     doSomethingWithColumn(column);  // this was the old if block
}   
for(Integer col : columns.keySet())  
{  
    switch(col)  
    {  
       ...  
    }
}
```

This reduces the if to only be executed once, as it is now outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: As previously stated, Iteration is needed anyway

Comment: @user01 yes but you haven't explained why it is needed.

Comment: because I need to do some calculations after fetching each item from the iterable & there is a single special case when I need to find a specific item in map.

Comment: @user01 can you post a small snippet of the code?  I have a feeling you may be using an incorrect data structure.  Please update your question with that information.

Comment: @user01 let me look over this and I will reply back

Answer (score 1):

If you use `if` statement then it will do the comparison as many times it runs the loop.

`HashMap` is meant for maintaining and retrieving the values using hash Keys and hence very efficient.

I would prefer to use `get(key)` over `if` statement to avoid several unnecessary comparisons.